# How to duplicate a specific product attribute (product.product) in Odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I want to duplicate an attribute of a product after the user selects it. However, I want it to only contain the previously selected values in its attributes and not the values of all the attributes of the original product, in order to only create 1 product variable.

I tried this:

```
for attribute in self.customization_attribute_line_ids.article_id:
   attribute.copy({
      'name': "{} - {}".format(attribute.name, self.name)
   })
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please show the `customization_attribute_line_ids` field declaration

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try getting those selected attributes through `self.env[models].active_ids`